# Передать значение value из input в data-quantity на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Помогите новичку написать простой скрипт, если так вообще возможно:
имеется форма добавления в корзину

```
<form action="/?add-to-cart=30" class="cart new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   <div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b">Количество</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
</div>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=30" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="30" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Купить</a>
```

как передать значение value из input в data-quantity на кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/*захватываем  элементы*/
var input = document.getElementById('quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b');
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
/* задаем обработчик события  Input*/
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  /*  и при каждом клике меняем значение атрибута а  data-quantity на значение inputa*/
  a[0].setAttribute('data-quantity', input.value);

  /* а консоль для наглядности, что работает можно удалить*/
  console.log(a[0].getAttribute('data-quantity'))
})
```

```html
<form action="/?add-to-cart=30" class="cart new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b">Количество</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
  </div>
  <a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=30" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="30" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Купить</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Получаете инпут `const input = document.getElementById('quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b')`, далее вам надо повесить обработчик на инпут `input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('product_type_simple')[0].setAttribute('data-quantity', e.target.value)
})`

Comment: при попытке нажать на кнопку js ругается Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Проверьте айдишник инпута, `const input = document.getElementById('quantity_5a0ea7cc0e93b')`

Comment: Спасибо,за помощь!